# Compile PHP-CPP on Windows Machine

Tags: php, makefile, mingw32, php-cpp

I`m trying develop a extension to PHP with PHP-CPP on Windows. I build the .a and .so of PHP-CPP with MingW, but, when i go build the extension the compiler not found the phpcpp.h.
My file Makefile:

```
NAME                    =   Teste
INI_DIR             =   /etc/php5/conf.d
EXTENSION_DIR           =   $(shell php-config --extension-dir)
EXTENSION           =   ${NAME}.so
INI                     =   ${NAME}.ini
COMPILER                =   g++
LINKER              =   g++
COMPILER_FLAGS      =   -Wall -c -O2 -std=c++11 -fpic -o
LINKER_FLAGS            =   -shared
LINKER_DEPENDENCIES =   -lphpcpp
RM                  =   rm -f
CP                  =   cp -f
MKDIR                   =   mkdir -p
SOURCES             =   $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJECTS             =   $(SOURCES:%.cpp=%.o)
all:                    ${OBJECTS} ${EXTENSION}
${EXTENSION}:           ${OBJECTS}
                ${LINKER} ${LINKER_FLAGS} -o $@ ${OBJECTS}         
${LINKER_DEPENDENCIES}
${OBJECTS}:
                ${COMPILER} ${COMPILER_FLAGS} $@ ${@:%.o=%.cpp}
install:        
                ${CP} ${EXTENSION} ${EXTENSION_DIR}
                ${CP} ${INI} ${INI_DIR}
clean:
                ${RM} ${EXTENSION} ${OBJECTS}
```

Folder Structure:

main.cpp
Makefile
phpcpp.a
phpcpp.so
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Pedro, sei que é antigo, mas você teve sucesso com Windows? Se puder dar uma mão la https://github.com/CopernicaMarketingSoftware/PHP-CPP/issues/433

Answer (score 0):

You can try to generate a visual studio project with cmake / cmake gui - there is a "CMakeLists.txt" in the root folder of "PHP-CPP" Directory.

Now you can compile it with msvc ... but be aware of the mixed code from c and c++ - there are some .c headers included - maybe you have to edit some compiler options ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following to generate an **.dll** of **phpcpp** with Linux (here **Ubuntu**):

First be sure you have installed the **PHP** version **7.4**. The "**dev**" as also the "**standard**" package of **PHP 7.4**.

Now compile the **PHPCPP** with "**sudo make**" in the main Folder of **PHPCPP**.

Now you got some "**.o**" files. These are located in the **/shared/zend/** of the main **PHPCPP** Folder.

Now you can create an "**.dll**" File out of these "**.o**" files - like the following (extracted from [here](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/dll.html#dll-link)):

```
sudo g++ -shared -o phpcpp.dll zval.o zendcallable.o valueiterator.o value.o throwable.o super.o streams.o streambuf.o stream.o script.o sapi.o object.o namespace.o module.o members.o base.o callable.o eval.o classbase.o classimpl.o constant.o constantfuncs.o error.o exception.o exception_handler.o exists.o extension.o extensionimpl.o file.o function.o functor.o global.o globals.o hashmember.o ini.o inivalue.o iteratorimpl.o
```

it is not completely tested ... be careful ...